# The best w_j confusion in xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, loss-function

from [XGBoost tutorial](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html#the-structure-score), it described:

> In this equation $w_j$ are independent with respect to each other, the form $G_j w_j + \frac{1}{2}(H_j+λ)w_j^2$ is quadratic and the best $w_j$ for a given structure $q(x)$
>
> and the best objective reduction we can get is:
>
> $w^∗_j = \frac{−G_j}{H_j+λ}$
>
> $obj^∗=\frac{−1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^T\frac{G^2_j}{H_j+λ} + γT$

So my confusion is:

if we would like to minimize the $obj$ function, clearly, the best way is to set:

$G_j w_j + \frac{1}{2}(H_j + λ) w_j^2 = 0$

thus we would have the best $w_j^*$ is:

$w_j^* = \frac{-2G_j}{H_j + λ}$

which is different with the official explanation.

anyone please help to point out where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to find an optimum you set the *derivative* of the function equal to 0. In your case that gives

$$ \frac{dG_j}{dw_J} = G_j + (H_j+\lambda)w_j = 0 $$

leading to

$$ w_j = \frac{-G_j}{H_j+\lambda}$$